# Перехватить событие меню android

Tags: android, qt

Как перехватить событие кнопок системного меню android: кнопка назад и кнопка выхода в главное меню?

Comment: @helpforprogrammer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь пример написан на QML: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29366/#208270

Если коротко, то примерно так же как и на PC перехватить нажатие любой клавиши.